# ng-repeat using custom filter doesn't work as intended: no values shown

Tags: angularjs, arrays, filter

I created this custom filter, it's supposed to take an array of objects that have *job* and *name* attributes and return an associative array which has *job* as a **key** and an *array of names* that share a job as a **value**.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('groupBy', function(){
        return function(input){
            if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
            var out = new Array();
            for (var crew of input){
                if(typeof out[crew.job] === 'undefined'){
                    out[crew.job] = new Array();
                }
                out[crew.job].push(crew.name);
            }           
            console.log(out);
            return out;
        }
    });
```

Result of the console.log:

```
Assistant Director: ["P.J. Voeten"]

Director: ["George Miller"]

Script Supervisor: ["Sophie Fabbri-Jackson"]

Writer: ["Nick Lathouris", "George Miller", "Brendan McCarthy"]
```

Then I intend to iterate through the array and print it like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in cast.crew | groupBy">
    <span class="bold">{{key}}:</span> 
    <span ng-repeat="name in value">{{name}}</span>
</li>
```

The *console.log* in the filter function shows that the array is created as intended, but it doesn't appear in the view, and it doesn't show an error message either.

Comment: If you try to add in the view {{ cast.crew | json }} what is the output?

Comment: I got this error (no changes in the view): Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: (key, value) in cast.crew | json, Duplicate key: string: , Duplicate value:  
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.2/ngRepeat/dupes?p0 (...)

Comment: add it in a new line above the for loop, like <span>{{ cast.crew | json }}</span>

Comment: Right, sorry; It outputs an array like this:  [ { "credit_id": "53d451210e0a262841002dd1", "department": "Writing", "id": 1027146, "job": "Writer", "name": "Nick Lathouris", "profile_path": null }, { "credit_id": "52fe4933c3a368484e11f76f", "department": "Directing", "id": 20629, "job": "Director", "name": "George Miller", "profile_path": "/smrCjoAwYyn91uBngUWHrak12MD.jpg" },(...) ]

Comment: It seems that the data you recieve is correct. What is instead the output after you apply your filter? Like <span>{{ cast.crew | groupBy | json }}</span>? It is very strange.

Comment: Just [ ] - Bear in mind that the groupBy function returns an array, not an object.

Comment: Aaaand, that was it. I changed the line **var out = new Array();** to **var out = new Object();** and the output is showing correctly now! Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out thanks to @GabrieleCiech - The problem was instancing the `out` variable in the filter function as an array an then trying to access it in the view as a json object. When I changed `var out = new Array();` to `var out = new Object();` it started working as inteded.